# Populating a DropDown from an Array returned by Javascript and Java

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events

I've got a drop down in the HTML that needs to be populated dynamically with a list of userIds from the database. Hence, I need to execute the JavaScript function calling the Java function to query the DB before the HTML page loads. As I need to execute the JS function before the page loads, I'm importing the Javascript (Users.js) in the head section and calling my JS function (`findActiveOrganisationsRequest('findActiveOrganisations')` on the `atload()` method in the Body tag of the HTML.

**Q1. Whats the best way to get that JS function to run before form loads so I can populate the dropdown? Will the above do the trick? My HTML is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Sample User Registration</title>     
    <script language="javascript" src="js/Users.js"> </script>
</head>

<body atload="findActiveUsersRequest(findActiveUsers)">
    <H2>User Registration</H2>                        
    <div id="userAccessForm" >
 <form name="userAccessForm" id="userAccessForm">
<div id="userAccessResults" style=" width : 364px; float:left;"></div><br>      <table width="100%" border="1px">
<tr><td>    <p>Organisation *<br>
    <select name="UserID" id="UserID">                  <option value="Choose your Organisation" selected>Choose Username</option>
    <option value="1">Dynamically populate User1</option>                   <option value="2">Dynamically populate User2</option>                   <option value="3">Dynamically populate user3</option>                   </select>   </p><td>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">              <input name="reset" type="reset" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<div id="UserResults" style=" width:353px; float:left;"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</form></body>
```

**Q2. Now, how do I populate the DropDown with the list returned back by the JS function. My Javascript function is as follows:**

```
function findActiveUsersRequest(findActiveUsers){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var returnText = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("UserResults").innerHTML=returnText;
};

var loadingHtml = "<img border=\"0\" src=\"images/busy.gif\" width=\"50\" /> Active Users Details...";
document.getElementById("UserResults").innerHTML=loadingHtml;
xmlhttp.open("GET","mets?action=users&userAction="+findActiveUsers);    
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

As evident, the last 2 lines of the above JS function send a HTTP request which gets caught by the servlet, which then:

1. checks for the parameters coming in the HTTP request,
2. Gets the results from the Database
3. Creates a `StringBuffer` array in response in the format as "UserID - UserName". But I'm not sure that this is the best way of doing it.. Any help/suggestions will be most appreciated!
4. Sends that response as follows:  `sendResponse(response.getWriter(), stringBuffer)`

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class RequestActionFactory {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Action getAction(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Retrieve action parameters
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    String userAction = request.getParameter("UserAction");


              // Validate
    if (action != null) {
        // Event request
        if (action.equals("users")) {
            List<UserIdDTO> userDTOList = getActiveUsers(); //Gets the UserIds from the DB
            StringBuffer[] stringBuffer = new StringBuffer[userDTOList.size()];                         
            for (UserIdDTO userDTO : userDTOList) {
                for(int i=0; i<userDTOList.size(); i++) {
                    stringBuffer[i] = new StringBuffer();
                    stringBuffer[i].append(responseValue(userDTO));
                }
            }           
            sendResponse(response.getWriter(), stringBuffer); 
        } 
    }       
    return null;        
}

private StringBuffer responseValue(UserIdDTO userDTO){
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    strBuffer.append(userDTO.getId());
    strBuffer.append(" - ");
    strBuffer.append(userDTO.getuserName());        
    return strBuffer;
}   

public static void sendResponse(PrintWriter writer, StringBuffer[] stringBuffer) {
    if (stringBuffer != null) {         
            for(int i=0; i<stringBuffer.length; i++) {                  
                if(null!=stringBuffer[i]) {
                    writer.write(stringBuffer[i].toString());
            }   
        } 
    } else {
        // TODO write to log            
    }       
}   
}
```

Once the Java Servlet sends a response back, it gets caught in the JS functions mentioned above as:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var returnText = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("UserResults").innerHTML=returnText;
};
```

So, I am successfully able to display the array in the UserResults DIV tag on my form as:

1 - john.Smith

2 - Adam.smith

3 - Peter.smith

But how can I use this array to populate my drop down in the form?

Any help will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To call you js function use jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    // You init code here
});
```

Use json to serialize your collection from java and deserialize it on javascript side.
On java side to serialize to json:

```
Collection<YourType> myCollection = ... ;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myCollection);

// Write json to response
```

On js side:

```
var myCollection = JSON.parse(responseText);
for(i = 0l i < myCollection.length; i++) {
    var element = myCollection[i];
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more how and where to use jQuery. Also, is there a way to do this without JSON? thanks

Comment: insert code in head section and also download (http://jquery.com/) and link jquery library to your jsp page.

Comment: Hi, how can I do this without using JSON please? In my Javascript, I've got an array variable of usernames that looks like: ["1-john.Smith","2-Adam.smith","3-Peter.smith"];